# ios can I change the default pass code screen behavior or create a combination of buttons that is always listening

Tags: ios

I want to know if it's possible to alter the behavior of the lock screen, lets say I have a normal user and a guest, so the normal user enters with the password and is the guest user wants to use the phone he has another password. All of this by code.

Another is create a combination of buttons like volume + - and home and whe the iPhone gets this combination does something.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, iOS doesn't have multi-user functionality and there's no public API for changing the lock screen.

Comment: Can I add a combination of buttons, then??

Comment: No, Apple don't let you reconfigure hardware buttons.